# Elasticsearch: How to query or aggregate on multi-value field counts

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to index email messages, each having a list of recipients, like this:

```
{
"To":[{"name":"John", "email":"john@gmail.com"}, {"name":"Jane", "email":"jane@yahoo.com"}],
"Body": "Blah blah blah"
}
```

I want to search in the body texts and perform aggregations *over messages that have more than one recipient only*. I tried to use **token_count** datatype and **value_count** aggregation, but neither seems to be applicable. Is there a way to define a filter over multi-value counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I guess your `To` field is a `nested` field. I don't see why shouldn't be like that if you want to really associate a `name` with an `email` address. Otherwise it would just be a list of names and a list of addresses without any association between them.

If your field is a `nested` one then its mapping should be this one:

```
    "To": {
      "type": "nested",
      "include_in_parent": true, 
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "email": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
```

Then the query to search for a certain number of email addresses:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "inline": "doc['To.name'].size() > counter",
            "params": {
              "counter": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Even if the field is not `nested`** the query above still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [Script Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) can work for you:

```
"bool" : {
    "must" : {
        // query on body
        ...
    },
    "filter" : {
        "script" : {
            "script" : {
                "inline" : "doc['To.name'].size() > param1"
                "params" : {
                    "param1" : 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But dont forget to enable scripting: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting

Comment: Turns out the proper way is doc['To.name'].size() or doc['To.name'].values.size(). The length method is not there anymore, probably since Elastic moved to Groovy.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for that. You had the working solution anyway :)